# Python || Creating new lines based on user input

Tags: python

I am wondering how you can let a given user input create new lines automatically.
Like for instance:

```
summary = input("Please write a short summary")
```

Let the user input for example be:

```
An age-old vendetta between two powerful families erupts into bloodshed. A group of masked Montagues risk further conflict by gatecrashing a Capulet party. A young lovesick Romeo Montague falls instantly in love with Juliet Capulet, who is due to marry her father's choice, the County Paris.
```

Now I actually want this to be displayed as:

```
An age-old vendetta between two powerful families erupts into bloodshed.
A group of masked Montagues risk further conflict by gatecrashing a Capulet party.
A young lovesick Romeo Montague falls instantly in love with Juliet Capulet, who is due to marry her father's choice, the County Paris.
```

As you can see in the last example, it is creating new lines each time.
I know you can create new lines with /n, but not how to import this into user inputs automatically, I hope you understand with the example given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this :

```
print(summary.replace('. ','.\n'))
```

Output:

```
>An age-old vendetta between two powerful families erupts into bloodshed.
 A group of masked Montagues risk further conflict by gatecrashing a Capulet party.
 A young lovesick Romeo Montague falls instantly in love with Juliet Capulet, who is due to marry her father's choice, the County Paris.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) module.

```py
import textwrap

print(textwrap.fill(myinput))
```

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely check this out.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to print users long input in different lines is as below

```
inp = "An age-old vendetta between two powerful families erupts into bloodshed. A group of masked Montagues risk further conflict by gatecrashing a Capulet party. A young lovesick Romeo Montague falls instantly in love with Juliet Capulet, who is due to marry her father's choice, the County Paris."
for i in inp.split("."):
    print(i.strip())
```

`inp` is the input taken from user.

`i.split(".")` is splitting the input text based on dots(".").

`i.strip()` is simply removing extra space (if any) at start or at end of line.

Answer (score 1):

This strips unnecessary whitespaces, and preserves dots:

```py
summary = input("Please write a short summary")
for line in summary.split("."):
    print(line.strip() + ".")
```